# Getting an error when adding modules to Angular app: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When no modules are added, everything works for the page using controller 'articles', when adding modules needed the page needing controller 'flow' everything works in flow, but 'articles' gives me this error.

```
var AC = angular.module('AC', ['ngRoute','ngMaterial','firebase'])

AC.controller('articles', function($scope){...})

AC.controller('flow', function($scope,$firebaseArray) {...}
```

My scripts:

```
<!-- START STYLE AND SCRIPTS -->    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
    <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular Material Library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<!-- END STYLE AND SCRIPTS -->
```

I addded the ngRoute module, it didn't work. Then I tried using the normal angular.js file as it apparently gives a specific error, didn't work as well.

Any help?

Comment: Try `AC.controller('articles',['$scope', function($scope){...}])` declaration

Comment: Thanks for responding! Unfortunately it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this order with the mathcing versions of angular-route and angular-fire

```
   <!-- Angular -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Angular Route -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Angular Material -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Firebase -->
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
        <!-- AngularFire -->
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
        <!-- our own app scripts -->
        <script src="js/concat/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for this question. The libraries were added on the flow.html file but not on the article.html file. The two solutions I provided at the bottom of the question does work as answered in previous questions.